Linting .js files in python
I'm dealing with some generated .js content and I would like to lint it for basic sanity checking. I tried to run eslint via subprocess
import subprocess
import tempfile
import os

# Create a temporary file, run ESLint validation, and clean up
def run_eslint_validation(content):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".js", mode='w') as tmp:
        tmp.write(content)
        js_file_path = tmp.name

    cmd = [
        'eslint',
        '--no-config-lookup',
        '--no-ignore',
        '--rule', 'semi: [error, always]', # always require semicolons
        js_file_path
    ]

    # Run validation
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
        print("CMD:", cmd)
        print("STDOUT:", result.stdout)
        return result.returncode == 0
    finally:
        # Remove the temporary file
        os.remove(js_file_path)

assert(run_eslint_validation("const x = 10")) == False, "ESLint validation failed"

My assert fails because eslint ignores the tempfile I wrote. It advises me to use --no-ignore, but I already have --no-ignore
CMD: ['eslint', '--no-config-lookup', '--no-ignore', '--rule', 'semi: [error, always]', '/var/folders/x7/n7rzl1zx5s96ft2p13c7bb_r0000gn/T/tmpng06us9y.js']
STDOUT:
/var/folders/x7/n7rzl1zx5s96ft2p13c7bb_r0000gn/T/tmpng06us9y.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore settings or use "--no-warn-ignored" to suppress this warning

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/lint/2test.py", line 29, in <module>
    assert(run_eslint_validation("const x = 10")) == False, "ESLint validation failed"
AssertionError: ESLint validation failed

update:
eslint works fine if I use:
    js_file_name = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.js"
    js_file_path = os.path.join('.', js_file_name)

    # Write the JavaScript content to the file
    with open(js_file_path, 'w') as js_file:
        js_file.write(content)

to write to the current directory. It's the path generated by tempfile that it wants to ignore.
